# Counterpart of "presidency" for a prime minister, as a one word?

Tags: single-word-requests

"Angela Merkel's presidency unraveled all of sudden." would be correct, if she were President. But she's the Prime Minister. How can this sentence be corrected, using a neat, appropriate expression (not necessarily one word, if not available.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Angela Merkel's premiership unrave**ll**ed all of sudden."

"Angela Merkel's premiership collapsed all of sudden."

"Angela Merkel lost her premiership suddenly."

"Angela Merkel lost her premiership suddenly, because..."

> **premiership** *noun*
>   1 The office or position of a prime minister or other head of government.
>   ‘candidates for the premiership’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/premiership)

Comment: Both *single-l* and *double-l* versions are in use. Have a look at the examples at [ODO’s definition 1.1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unravel): the *double-l* form is used in the primary example, but the “more examples” button shows examples using the *single-l* form.

Comment: Good for you. :)